# Apps Script to update Timestamp when data is inserted automatically in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

This code works fine when data is edited in Column 3 or being copy-pasted but if the cursor remains at column 1 at the time of the whole row being copy/pasted, it won't update and secondly, if salesforce sends data to column 3, it doesn't work that time too, please help me here.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = s.getName();

  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var row = r.getRow();
  var ar = s.getActiveRange();
  var arRows = ar.getNumRows()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the active range = "+ar.getA1Notation()+", the number of rows = "+ar.getNumRows());
  

  if( r.getColumn() == 3 && sName == 'Sheet1') { //which column to watch on which sheet
   // loop through the number of rows
    for (var i = 0;i<arRows;i++){
      var rowstamp = row+i;
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F' + rowstamp.toString()).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"); //which column to put timestamp in
    }
  }
 }//setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

Three important things to know:

- As it is also stated in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite), the `onEdit` triggers are triggered upon **user** edits. This function won't be triggered by formula nor another script. If salesforce or any other service except for the user, edits column `C` the `onEdit` trigger is not going to be activated. Workarounds exist, but these workarounds depend on the context of your specific problem. I would advice you to search or ask a specific question about it.
- Regarding the other issue you have, you should get rid of active ranges and take advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). This object contains information regarding the edit/edits user made.
- As it is recommended by the [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) you should not set values in the sheet iteratively but you can to that in one go by selecting a range of cells and set the values. In your case, you want to set the same value in all of the cells in the desired range, hence `setValue` is used instead of `setValues`. But the idea is to get rid of the `for` loop.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = s.getName();
  var ar = e.range;
  var row = ar.getRow();
  var arRows = ar.getNumRows()  
  if( ar.getColumn() == 3 && sName == 'Sheet1') { 
      s.getRange(row,6,arRows).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
 }
```

**Note:**

Again, `onEdit` is a trigger function. You are **not** supposed to execute it manually and if you do so you will actually get errors (because of the use of the event object). All you have to do is to **save** this code snippet to the script editor and then it will be triggered automatically upon edits.

Comment: Thanks, Marios, I appreciate your prompt response.
I tried running your code, but It is throwing the error "  Cannot read property 'source' of undefined".
I replaced it by SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() even, but then it showed me the range undefined error,
Any hint,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am sorry, I realized it now it's working fine when column C has an active cursor and data gets inserted or updated.
Thanks

Comment: In the event object: source = A Spreadsheet object, representing the Google Sheets file to which the script is bound. Spreadsheet. When I stringify the event object I see {}. There is no indication f which sheet within the spreadsheet was changed. Are triggers only useful when there is a single sheet or which sheet is changed does not matter?

Comment: @aNewb thanks for your comment. `e.source` gives you indeed the `spreadsheet` object the script is bound. From that object you can get the sheet that was edited: `sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()`. And from that you can get the name of the sheet or any other info of that sheet (`gid`) or whatever. For example `sheet.getName()`. Therefore you can put the name of the sheet as a condition (as my answer above) to execute some code only for particular sheets (tabs) in the spreadsheet file.

Comment: @Marios,
Can you please help me in modifying your code for purpose of copying and pasting the entire row which involves change/edit in column 3 cell too, Please.

Comment: I don't see you handling deleting a row. When I test your code I see a time stamp on an empty row..It looks like you could identify this by the absense of oldValue in the event.

Comment: I don't see you handling deleting a row. When I test your code I see a time stamp on an empty row..It looks like you could identify this by the absense of oldValue in the event. However, you will not get a timestamp if you copy a row in either!?!?

Comment: @aNewb I recommend you create a post to ask a question so you will be able to provide all the details needed (screenshots, input,outputs,code) etc so it will be easier to give a specific answer. Now you are asking question about a code that solved a different question of yours which, but also the comment section is not meant for this purpose. Thanks for your understanding.