# Insert the date/time an individual tab was last updated (google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

I have a data dashboard in Google Sheets that synthesizes data from several different data sources. These data sources are dropped into the same Google Sheet file, each on separate tabs. Different team members are responsible for updating each of the individual data tabs, which is done by pulling reports from various programs and pasting the new data into their respective data tab.
*Note: I realize this process of pasting in data from reports from different programs is inefficient. Unfortunately the systems we use don't all speak to one another, so this is the best way we've found so far to analyze data across our systems.*

**The goal:** I would like to have a cell on each data tab where it lists the last date and time **that individual tab (sheet)** was updated. For example, if I update the data on Tab 1, I would like the date/time stamp to update on Tab 1 but not on Tab 2. The date/time stamp on Tab 2 should only update when I add new data to Tab 2.

I have tried the script pasted below (from [the Question/Answer linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717148/apps-script-to-update-timestamp-when-data-is-inserted-automatically-in-google-sh)), and it *does* update the date/time on the tab:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = s.getName();
  var ar = e.range;
  var row = ar.getRow();
  var arRows = ar.getNumRows()  
  if( ar.getColumn() == 3 && sName == 'Sheet1') { 
      s.getRange(row,6,arRows).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
 }
```

The problem is that it *also* updates the date/time on Tab 1 when I update the data on Tab 2.

**What script do I use so that it updates the date/time on Tab 1 only when the data on Tab 1 is updated? And would update the date/time on Tab 2 when the data on Tab 2 is updated?**

Answer (score 0):

#### Change date cell A1 in every Sheet that is edit by a user

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  sh.getRange(1,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
 }
```

**If you wish to exclude some sheets:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const excl = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(~excl.indexOf(sh.getName()))return;//this could allow you to exclude some sheets
  sh.getRange(1,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
 }
```

I chose A1 in this case

Comment: -  Thank you! Are you able to help explain the first solution you posted? I'm not quite understanding how it would work to only trigger the date change by looking at edits on the single tab.

Comment: You said that you want to put the current time in a certain cell on every sheet whenever the sheet is edited so this will put the time in A1 whenever any sheet is edited